# Displaying an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506602/displaying-an-associative-array-in-php)

I am trying to build a function that extracts information from a database and inserts it into an associative array in PHP using mysql_fetch_assoc, and return the array so another function can display it.
and i need way to display the returned assoc array this should be a different function from the first one 
thank you for ur help :)